# Two event for background image

Tags: javascript, jquery-events

I'm trying to create something to change wallpaper by clicking on picture or by clicking on a button.

Separately it's works, but when I click on a thumbnail wallpaper change and when I click on button I select a picture and it's ok but after if I want to click again on a thumbnail the problem appears, if someone can help me that would be very appreciated.

I created an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nathel/cxf2pgky/3/)

```
$('ul#images li').click(function(e){
  $('ul#images li').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
  });  
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var source = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    $('.outer').css('background', 'url('+source+')');
});

$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clicking on the pictures sets a background for the .outer div, the button sets the background for an image tag. Why not have the button set the background for the .outer div too? Then remove the image tag altogether. I think then it would work as you expect, example below.

In the below example...
I changed setting `background`, to setting `backgound-image` so setting it does not override the other background css.

```js
$('ul#images li').click(function(e){
  $('ul#images li').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
  });  
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var source = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    $('.outer').css('background-image', 'url('+source+')');
});
 
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    //$('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('.outer').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result+')');
}
```

```css
*,  *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul, ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a,
a:visited, 
a:focus {
  text-decoration: inherit;
 font-weight: inherit;
 color: inherit;
}

.outer {
  background: black;
  background: url('https://hdfondsdecran.com/image/201609/71/nuage-vue-de-dessus-multicolore-merveilleux.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  @include transform(scale(1.1));
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(black,0.6);
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 7em;
  font-size: 8vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(black,0.6);
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
  @include transition(all 0.4s ease);
}

button:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

ul#images li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul#images li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul#images li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul#images li img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
<div class="overlay">
  </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <br><br><h2>Change Background Image:</h2><br>
      <ul id="images">
        <li class="active"><img src="https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/86/37/63601592852769/0/get-ios-10s-new-wallpaper-any-phone.1280x600.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://www.itl.cat/pngfile/big/2-20588_ios-wallpaper-iphone-wallpaper-hd-desktop.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/42/65/79/426579e96e9333ed9518c2fd9d3e5482.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a1/4d/e0/a14de021c4fa8049d2d798d5b98d7419.jpg" /></li>
        <input type="file" id="uploader" />
          <label for="uploader">Parcourir</label>
      </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```